# Spring - Adding a file name to an attribute in an xml file node

Tags: spring

I am new to Spring and I am trying to get the XML input file name in my spring app added to a node as an attribute so I can get the name during the XSLT transformation (happening in Saxon-HE) and add it to a tag in the transformed message.

For testing purposes, I am reading in the file and trying to use an xpath-transformer to add the attribute to the "Channels" node but the message doesn't get passed to the output.

I tried using a different output name but it gave me a bean error when I ran my app.

**App Context** :

```
<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter
    id="mdmhe.fieldpro.inboundFileAdapter"
    directory="${mdmhe.fieldpro.inputfilelocation}"
    channel="mdmhe.fieldpro.transformChannel" auto-create-directory="true"
    filename-pattern="*.*">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="1000"></int:poller>
</int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:channel id="mdmhe.fieldpro.transformChannel"/>

<int-xml:xpath-transformer
    input-channel="mdmhe.fieldpro.transformChannel"
    xpath-expression="//Channels/@filename=payload.name"
    evaluation-type="STRING_RESULT"
    output-channel="mdmhe.fieldpro.transformChannel"/>

<int-file:outbound-channel-adapter
    id="mdmhe.fieldpro.outboundFileAdapter"
    channel="mdmhe.fieldpro.transformChannel"
    directory="${mdmhe.fieldpro.outputfilelocation}"
    auto-create-directory="true" />
```

**XML Input snippet** :

```xml
<MeterReadingDocument xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-Instance" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <ImportExportParameters CreateResubmitFile="false">
        <DataFormat DSTTransitionType="NIST_Compliant" ReadingTimestampType="MeterDefault" />
    </ImportExportParameters>
    <Channels>
        <Channel ReadingsInPulse="false" IsRegister="true">
            <ChannelID EndPointUOMID="2.16.840.1.114416.0.322604884:Wh d" />
            <Readings>
                <Reading Value="1881361.663" ReadingTime="2020-05-12T00:00:00" />
            </Readings>
        </Channel>
```

The log shows the payload as false after the transformation :

```
7/14/20 15:13:46:268 EDT [task-scheduler-2] DEBUG o.s.i.channel.DirectChannel.send(449) - postSend (sent=true) on channel 'mdmhe.fieldpro.transformChannel', message: GenericMessage [payload=false, headers={id=b0c94574-bd8a-9ca3-0b01-11c86cd88d2a, timestamp=1594754026253}]
7/14/20 15:13:46:268 EDT [task-scheduler-2] DEBUG o.s.i.channel.DirectChannel.send(449) - postSend (sent=true) on channel 'mdmhe.fieldpro.transformChannel', message: GenericMessage [payload=C:\users\d47219\mdmitron\fieldprodata\ExampleFieldProInputShort.txt, headers={id=cc146ae6-516d-d20b-3b6d-b4e864fdc1d3, timestamp=1594754026215}]
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by 'x-path-transformer'? You use x-path as part of a transformation, but I'm not sure how you are going to use a transformer to add a node, then do a transformation to get the value out again.

An XSLT transform can only output values that are already in the XML, or parameters passed in at the start of the transform. Perhaps you could pass the filename as a parameter, instead of adding it to the XML?

Comment: I was looking through the Spring documentation and I found xpath-transformer, this goes in the Application Context file (see above), I thought it would add the attribute to the node in the input file before I do the xslt transformation then I would have it available in the xslt transformation.  A parameter sounds like it would work too, I'm just not sure how to access it inside the xslt.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to pass in the filename using a parameter, first I added a header enricher which put the filename in the header properties then I added the parameter to my xslt transformation calling it with headers.file_name.

```
'''<int:channel id="mdmhe.fieldpro.transformChannel"/> 
    <int:header-enricher id="mdmhe.fieldpro.headerEnricher"
    input-channel="mdmhe.fieldpro.transformChannel"
    output-channel="mdmhe.fieldpro.transformChannel">
    <int:header name="file_name" expression="payload.name"/>
</int:header-enricher>

<int-xml:xslt-transformer id="mdmhe.fieldpro.xsltXformHHF2IMDLike" 
    input-channel="mdmhe.fieldpro.stringChannel"
    output-channel="mdmhe.fieldpro.outputChannel"
    xsl-templates="mdmhe.fieldpro.HHF2IMDLikeTemplates">
    <int-xml:xslt-param name="filename" expression="headers.file_name"/>
</int-xml:xslt-transformer>'''
```

XSLT: I added the parameter to my xslt

```
 '''<xsl:param name="filename" />'''
```

then called it with $filename in the xslt:

```
   '''<xsl:element name="externalId">
          <xsl:value-of select="$filename"></xsl:value-of>
      </xsl:element>'''
```

END Result:

```
  '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <D1-InitialLoadIMD>
       <preVEE>
         <imdType>D1IL</imdType>
         <externalId>ExampleFieldProInputShort.txt</externalId>
         <dvcIdN>2.16.840.1.114416.0.322604884</dvcIdN>
         <externalUOM>VARh d</externalUOM>'''
```